# header not aligning with columns when scrollable enabled JSF Primefaces 6.0

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I am developing web using PrimeFaces 6.0 components. On 
`<p:dataTable>` component when we set `scrollable="true"` option, columns headers alignment goes wrong.

Following is my code snippet:

```
<p:fieldset legend="Machine Test Match" id="panel233" toggleable="true"  toggleSpeed="500"  >
            <!--<p:panel id="panel233" header=" Machine Test Match" style="height:325px;border: none">-->
            <p:dataTable id="testmatchtable" var="testMatchvalues"   value="#{manufactureBean.listTestMatchata}" filteredValue="#{manufactureBean.filteredManufacture}"  editable="true" 
                         styleClass="mystyle" tableStyle="table-layout:auto;width:100% important!;"    rowKey="#{testMatchvalues.testId}"   scrollRows="10" scrollable="true"   scrollHeight="230"  rows="40"  liveScroll="true"       selection="#{manufactureBean.testMatchModel}" selectionMode="single"                         resizableColumns="true"      > 


                <p:column headerText="Test ID" filterBy="#{testMatchvalues.testId}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:35px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{testMatchvalues.testId}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Test Desc" filterBy="#{testMatchvalues.testDesc}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:35px" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{testMatchvalues.testDesc}" />
                </p:column>


                <p:column headerText="Specimen Desc" filterBy="#{testMatchvalues.specimenDesc}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:35px" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{testMatchvalues.specimenDesc}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Path Test Desc" filterBy="#{testMatchvalues.pathTestDesc}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:35px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{testMatchvalues.pathTestDesc}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Path Param Name"  style="width:35px" filterBy="#{testMatchvalues.parameterName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{testMatchvalues.parameterName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Additional Factor"  style="width:35px" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{testMatchvalues.additionFactor}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Multiply Factor"  style="width:35px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{testMatchvalues.multiplyFactor}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Machine Host Code"  style="width:35px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{testMatchvalues.machineHostCode}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Active"  style="width:35px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{testMatchvalues.active}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            <!--</p:panel>-->
        </p:fieldset>
```

Code taken from https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml

Attached image shows the problem clearly as column headers and data is not aligned properly.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AMSg.png)

Comment: Probably not super important but fyi to start, in your table style, important! should be !important

Comment: and try if you remove the tablestyle at  all...

Comment: @Kukeltje , I tried your suggestion .Now column alignment seems to be fine but problem is that I am not getting row data properly. If String is larger than column width it cuts it and remaining string looses.

Comment: Then use css to wrap the content

Answer (score 0):

For **p:column**, `width="4%"` works for me rather than using `'4px'`